# Bootstrap 4 - justify content center on flexbox child (override flex parent container)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Using Bootstrap 4, I'm trying to center an img at the botton middle of the main div. However, it does not center.

How it should be:
[image]

```
<!doctype html>
          <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <title>Hello, world!</title>
              <!-- Required meta tags -->
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

              <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">


               <style>

                 section.masthead2{
                    background-color:orange;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-attachment: scroll;
                    background-position: center center;
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    background-size: cover;
                    height:80vh;
                  }
                  .gear {
                    height: 50px;
                  }
                  .botonhome{
                    background-color:#eb6626;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    padding-left:2em;
                    padding-right:2em;
                    font-family:'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
                    font-weight:500;
                    border-radius:0.5em;
                    font-size:1.2em;
                  }
               </style>

            </head>
            <body>
              <section class="container-fluid masthead2  d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <h1 class="textoprincipal ">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                      <a class="btn botonhome mr-3" routerLink="/backoffice/job" routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing1</a>
                      <a class="btn  botonhome" routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing2</a>
                    </div>         
                </div>
                <div class="row d-flex align-self-end ">
                <div class="col-12">
                <img class="gear text-center" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Cog%2C_Web_Fundamentals.svg">
                </div>
                </div>
            </section>
              <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
              <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
            </body>
          </html>
```

Since the main container-fluid has d-flex both subsequents div rows are place one beside each other horizontally.
Below is how it would look like without d-flex in the main container-fluid (used a background color for the gear to differentiate)
[image]

After d-flex is applied in the main container-fluid (since I need to align and justify the main title and buttons centered) the gear icon image is positioned on the left corner due to d-flex in main container. 
[image]
How would I made this element d-block override from it's main container-fluid so I can then move it at the bootom middle of the div?
Can this be achieved via Bootstrap classes?

I can not make two main container-fluid, since the background will be an image.

Comment: can you add your css

Comment: share your css code.So that we can look through it.

Comment: add 'transform' property in your css file corresponding  to your desired img tag

Comment: I've updated the code with CSS so it's easier to understand. Can this be achieved via bootstrap clases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I've the posted the answer with `img` tag also...please check it...

I've posted the answer but you want to change it to class corresponding to your class given in your `img` tag.

**NOTE :**
The below code snippet is an example of a `Button`tag.In your case change it to img. Now I've included `img` Tag also in the below example

```css
 .gear {
         height: 50px;
         position:absolute;
         margin-left:50%;
         margin-right:50%;
         transform: translateX(-50%);
       }
```

```html
<img class="gear" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/5/7/f/1297719143988960365gear_red.png" style="width:50px;height:50px;"/>
```

Comment: I've posted an answer for your problem...I think this will help you to solve the problem...Please check it and update me...If it feels helpful for you then please accept and upvote it...Thank you... Good Luck!!!:)

Comment: Hi, I updated my post with CSS for clarification since I was not able to apply your answer in my code. Can not this be achieved via bootstrap?

Comment: I've updated my answer...Copy the CSS code of `.gear` class to your code and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap image in `<div>` and give `text-align:center` to it

```css
.imgcenter{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="col-12">
              <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h1>
       </div>
      <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a class="btn mr-3" routerLink="/backoffice/job" 
  routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing1</a>
        <a class="btn  botonhome" routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" 
      routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing2</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="imgcenter">
        <img class="d-flex align-self-end justify-content-center" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/5/7/f/1297719143988960365gear_red.png" width= '50'>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I tried that but did not work. I've updated my post with CSS. Do you think this can be achieved with Bootstrap?

Comment: you can achieve it by bootstrap3...check out my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by bootstrap 3

`<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Using `class="text-center"`

```html
<!doctype html>
          <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <title>Hello, world!</title>
              <!-- Required meta tags -->
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

              <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
              <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


               <style>

                 section.masthead2{
                    background-color:orange;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-attachment: scroll;
                    background-position: center center;
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    background-size: cover;
                    height:100vh;
                  }
                  .gear {
                    height: 50px;
                  }
                  .botonhome{
                    background-color:#eb6626;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    padding-left:2em;
                    padding-right:2em;
                    font-family:'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
                    font-weight:500;
                    border-radius:0.5em;
                    font-size:1.2em;
                  }
               </style>

            </head>
            <body>
              <section class="container-fluid masthead2  d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex text-center">
                        <h1 class="textoprincipal ">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 d-flex text-center">
                      <a class="btn botonhome mr-3" routerLink="/backoffice/job" routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing1</a>
                      <a class="btn  botonhome" routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" routerLinkActive="active" role="button">Testing2</a>
                    </div>         
                </div>
                <div class="row d-flex align-self-end ">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <img class="gear text-center" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Cog%2C_Web_Fundamentals.svg">
                </div>
                </div>
            </section>
              <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
              <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
              <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
            </body>
          </html>
```

Comment: And I do not have idea about bootstrap 4